# What is the proper way to enable and disable GLES20 atributes?

Tags: android, attributes, drawing, opengl-es-2.0, texture2d

Firsty what am I creating: 2d tile based rpg game. 
What I am currently doing I will post here, and comment some spots that I am not sure if I am using them correctly.

In GlSurfaceViewRenderer:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
   //I enable some attributes
   //Don't know if its needed in GLES20, there isnt GL20.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT attribute at all
   GLES20.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST); 
   //next I don't really know if I need them all:
   GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
   GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
   GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);// No culling of back faces
   GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DITHER);
   GLES20.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
   GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   // for transperent pixels
   GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
   GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

   //Load shaders:  (1 vertex and fragment shader I hope is enouph)
   iProgId = Utils.LoadProgram(vertexShaderCode, fragmentShaderCode);
   GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);
   // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
   mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgId, "vPosition");
   // get handle to textures shader's a_TexCoordinate member
   mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgId, "a_TexCoordinate");
   // get handle to transformation matrix
   mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uMVPMatrix");

  //Now in here not sure:   some people enable arrays in every draw frame, I do it once:
  // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices   
  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
  // Enable a handle to the texture vertices 
  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, ratio, -ratio, 1, -1, 1, 10000);
    //.... and other
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
   GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   //set camera position
   Matrix.setLookAtM(...);
   Matrix.multiplyMM(...);

   //begin drawing:
   for(Sprite spr : Sprite_list){

      spr.draw(){
         //whats happening in draw:
         //First setting the location of the sprite:
         Matrix.setIdentityM(...x & y...);
         Matrix.translateM(...);
         Matrix.setIdentityM(...);
         Matrix.multiplyMM(...);

         //Some developers enables vertex attrib arrays here and then disables at the                                        end of this drawing method. But I enable it in on surface created and don't disable it, maybe it's faster this way, not sure.
         // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
         GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLRenderer.mPositionHandle, DIMENSION,            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
         // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
         GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLRenderer.mTextureCoordinateHandle, DIMENSION, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, textureBuffer);

         GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textID);
         GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLRenderer.mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, GLRenderer.mMVPMatrix, 0);

         GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

      }

   }

}
```

And everything works, for now, but I really not sure if I am doing any mistakes here, can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The code itself does not necessarily do anything incorrect from what I can see.
Apart from GLES20.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING); as it's not a feature available in ES2.
Although the code is very limited to what it will be able to do. Reason is that you're uploading most of the rendering states in surfaceCreated, not when you actually might need them/change renderstates.

For example:

> //Now in here not sure:   some people enable arrays in every draw frame, I do it once:
>   // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
>   GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
>   // Enable a handle to the texture vertices 
>   GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);

It's perfectly fine to just enable the attribute arrays at one place, however if you would like to utilize a different shader program for a particular piece of geometry in your scene, this would become quite problematic.

Consider this, if you would want to change program, you need to potentially Enable/Disable the particular attributes for that program. You would also need to bind the program (glUseProgram)

Therefore as you referenced yourself in the code comment, that others normally enable/disable these during rendering is for that specific reason.
However it's not just for attribute streams but also all types of renderstates like changing program, enabling Cullmode, blending and so forth.

Now one shouldn't go crazy and just upload and change all of these before every draw call, as changing states are expensive.
One will try to batch all the draw calls that will use the same type of renderstates and resources such as textures/programs and so forth together to minimize number of renderstates changes.
So in your renderloop you would then render the sorted scene of renderable objects, then upload any renderstate that might need to change or been invalidated.